# Add a column value in a row based on every values of this same row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, h2o, spark-structured-streaming

My question might be dumb or anything else. But I was wondering :

- I want to do structured streaming
- I want to both aggregate and score the data with a Sparkling Water model

So I have this

```
val data_processed = data_raw
      .withWatermark("timestamp", "10 minutes")
      .groupBy(window(col("timestamp"),"1 minute"))
      .agg(
       *** all aggregations ***
      )
```

What I want to add is like :

```
.withColumn("row_scored",scoring(all_others_cols))
```

So for every row in structured streaming it will score after the aggregation. But I don't think that can be possible. So I'm wondering if you think of another approach.

I'm using Sparkling Water so the scoring functions needs a H2O Frame. I was thinking to create an udf like that :

- select all other columns,
- create a row and transform it to dataframe
- convert the dataframe composed of one row to H2O Frame
- predict the H2O Frame of one row
- transform the prediction from H20 Frame to dataframe
- get the score in the dataframe to double and return it with udf

But I don't think that's quite optimised, maybe you have a fresh approach or remarks that will make see another way to do this.

Thanks in advance